# Pick a specific generic function implementation

Tags: typescript

I am refactoring some typescript classes which depend on each other.
To decouple required dependencies I use `Pick` utility type, and it works well except for generic functions.
I need to somehow pick only specific functions based on generic.
Here is simplified code:

```
export type AgentEvents = {
    'token-change': string | null;
    'something-else': string;
};

export class Agent {
    private readonly emitter = mitt<AgentEvents>();

    public token: string | null = null;

    public setToken(token: string | null) {
        this.token = token;
        this.emitter.emit('token-change', token);
    }

    public on<T extends keyof AgentEvents>(
        event: T,
        handler: (data: AgentEvents[T]) => void,
    ) {
        this.emitter.on(event, handler);
    }
}

type T = Agent['on'];
export interface AgentI
    extends Pick<Agent, 'token'> {
    on: T<'token-change'>; // i don't need 'something-else' in the AgentI interface, since Actor class does not require it
}

export class Actor {
    constructor(private readonly agent: AgentI) {
        this.agent.on('token-change', () => {
            console.log('token change');
        });
    }
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: ① What's `mitt`?  Is this a [mre]? ② Maybe you're looking for [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJrl5W) using an instantiation expression?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?